# How to auto refresh browser with webpack on change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have a this file `backend-dev.js` which is mostly webpack configuration. I use it to run my express server from the bundled file. It stays on and restarts the server on any change. Is there any possible configuration can be added to auto refresh the browser too whenever I change the code?
This is what I have in the `backend-dev.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const compiler = webpack({
    // add your webpack configuration here
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    /*plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Project Demo',
            hash: true,
            template: './views/index.ejs' // Load a custom template (ejs by default see the FAQ for details)
      })
    ],*/
    node: {
        __dirname: false
    },
    target: 'node'
});

const watchConfig = {
    // compiler watch configuration
    // see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
};

let serverControl;

compiler.watch(watchConfig, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);
        if (err.details) {
            console.error(err.details);
        }
        return;
    }

    const info = stats.toJson();

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
        info.errors.forEach(message => console.log(message));
        return;
    }

    if (stats.hasWarnings()) {
        info.warnings.forEach(message => console.log(message));
    }

    if (serverControl) {
        serverControl.kill();
    }

    // change filename to the relative path to the bundle created by webpack, if necessary(choose what to run)
    serverControl = spawn('node', [path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/bundle.js')]);

    serverControl.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
    serverControl.stderr.on('data', data => console.error(data.toString()));
});
```

Comment: use webpack-hot-middleware to support hot reload module.

Answer (score 0):

**Excellent question: I solved it in the following way:**

*express has two modules you can install to refresh in hot without refreshing the browser, and it will refresh automatically: I leave you my configuration.*

> npm i livereload
>
> npm i connect-livereload

```
const livereload = require('livereload');

const connectLivereload = require('connect-livereload');

const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();

liveReloadServer.watch(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'frontend'));

const app = express();

app.use(connectLivereload());
```

[image]

*Note that the folder you want to monitor is in dist/frontend. Change the folder you want to monitor so that it works: To monitor the backend I am using NODEMON*

**livereload** open a port for the browser in the backend to expose the changes: how does the connection happen? It's easy; express with "**connect-livereload**" and inject a script that monitors that port: if a change occurs, the browser is notified by express, **and the browser will refresh for you**.

I leave The information as simple as possible to test, and I do not recommend using it like this: To use it you must separate the development and production environments. I keep it simple so that it is easy to understand.

*Here I leave the most relevant link I found: I hope it will be helpful too.*

https://bytearcher.com/articles/refresh-changes-browser-express-livereload-nodemon/