# Hot reloading in a React app with express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

As of now I have a boilerplate set up for a MERN application having an express server on the backend and react on the frontend. I intend to set up hot reloading in my app- whenever there's any change in the react code without having to refresh the whole app(HMR).

I have `webpack-dev-server` and `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` installed. I've also tried to use `--hot` in the `webpack` script in `package.json`. If I run `npm run webpack`, the code compiles, and the server starts on `localhost:8080`. It gives me something like this, which is not what I want really. I don't know it looks like it's showing me the root directory.

[image]

On the other hand, if I run `npm start`, the server starts and displays the react component, which is what I want, but with hot reloading. Right now, I have to refresh the page in order to see the changes.

[image]

So, I'm trying to understand what's really going on? Is there a way to add hot reloading when I type `npm start`?

**client/index.js**

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./containers/App"

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

**client/containers/App.js**

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**client/components/HomePage.js**

```js
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React HomePage</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

**routes/index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Travel Forum' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views/index.ejs**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
    "webpack": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --hot"
  },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
/* eslint-disable */
var webpack = require("webpack")
var path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: ["./client/index.js"],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          { loader: "sass-loader" },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist/bundle/",
    publicPath: "/static/",
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "bundle.css",
    }),
  ],
}
```

**app.js**

```js
const createError = require("http-errors")
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const path = require("path")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const logger = require("morgan")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const indexRouter = require("./routes/index")
const userRouter = require("./routes/users")

const app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.use(logger("dev"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  const webpack = require("webpack")
  const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config")
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

  app.use(
    require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    })
  )

  app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler))
}

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/travel-forum",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false },
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Not connected to the database")
    } else {
      console.log("Connected to the database")
    }
  }
)

app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter)
app.use("/*", indexRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404))
})

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {}

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500)
  res.render("error")
})

module.exports = app
```

Comment: Why you don't use create-react-app and set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in package.json to your express api.

Comment: IMO if you are using MERN just use Next js. Has bakesn in SSR and Routing and Hot module reloading and the ability to generate static sites.

Comment: Alright. So, MERN doesn't support Hot Reloading?? @JoeLloyd

Comment: @metalHeadDev it can, depends if you build it in. But it's a "waste" of dev time when there are frameworks that come with it baked in. unless you want to get to grips with how webpack is working with dev servers etc.

Comment: Alright, cool. Next.js and Gatsby are good for static sites. I'll look into Next, for sure. Thanks.

Comment: in webpack.config.js add code in module.exports:  devServer: {contentBase: './views' }; to set open directory.

Comment: @JingJiang doesn't work. I have to refresh the page to see changes.

Comment: sorry, I thought you might want to open dev directory. for hot load ,you can try set code in module.exports: entry:["./client/index.js",'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080', 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server']

Comment: some refer:https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpacks-hmr-react-hot-loader-the-missing-manual-232336dc0d96

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610921/14257757

Answer (score 1):

** I solved it in the following way:**

*express has two modules you can install to refresh in hot without refreshing the browser, and it will refresh automatically: I leave you my configuration.*

> npm i livereload
>
> npm i connect-livereload

```
const livereload = require('livereload');

const connectLivereload = require('connect-livereload');

const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();

liveReloadServer.watch(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'frontend'));

const app = express();

app.use(connectLivereload());
```

[image]

*Note that the folder you want to monitor is in dist/frontend. Change the folder you want to monitor so that it works: To monitor the backend I am using NODEMON*

**livereload** open a port for the browser in the backend to expose the changes: how does the connection happen? It's easy; express with "**connect-livereload**" and inject a script that monitors that port: if a change occurs, the browser is notified by express, **and the browser will refresh for you**.

I leave The information as simple as possible to test, and I do not recommend using it like this: To use it you must separate the development and production environments. I keep it simple so that it is easy to understand.

*Here I leave the most relevant link I found: I hope it will be helpful too.*

https://bytearcher.com/articles/refresh-changes-browser-express-livereload-nodemon/